# Why is `write()` performed via a `call` instruction instead of an interrupt?

Tags: macos, assembly, clang, x86-64

I was trying to play a bit in assembly.
My understanding is that sys calls are made through an interrupt generated by the `syscall` instruction.

However after compiling a simple program on my computer using `clang -S`:

```
int main() {
  write(0, "HI", 2);
  return 0;
}
```

The relevant assembly generated is:

```
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rsi
    movl    $2, %edx
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _write
```

Why is that ?

Is there a way to see the actually sys call being performed on OS X ?

Comment: I don't know anithing about OS X, but generally sys calls are compiled inside standard libraries. Probably you'll find it inside _write or in his subcalls.

Comment: The `write` function does some extra processing to set up `errno` correctly.  It's also there so you can hook it with your own code if desired and so the operating system can change the way it does system calls without programs noticing.

Comment: The system calls can be found in `unistd_32.h` and `unistd_64.h` for 32-bit and 64-bit, respectively. the *"write"* syscall is actually `__NR_write` (with no. `4` for the 32-bit call and `1` for the 64-bit call). There are several variants of the *"write"* syscall.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The canonical header file is `<sys/syscall.h>` which defines `SYS_XXX` macros for the system call numbers.  It does the right thing depending on bit size.  Note further that OP is programming on macOS, not Linux where the numbers are different.

Comment: Good point, I got my Macs jumbled with my clones on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're calling a function from the C standard library. That function may or may not wrap a syscall, could use an unexpected syscall (e.g. a more modern one than the original), and generally has to perform various setup and teardown operation to adapt between the C and syscall calling conventions.

The wrapper is usually fairly thin, but it's still a wrapper (e.g. on linux syscalls usually return either a success or `-errno` in case of failure, the libc then has to check for failure, stash the errno in the corresponding threadlocal and return the "proper" value defined by the standard or POSIX instead).

Comment: On MacOS the raw system calls set CF to indicate that the return value is an `errno` code, unlike Linux where error codes are `-4095..-1` for all syscalls, so yes same difference.  The library wrapper branches on that and sets `errno` and returns `-1` on error.  For some system calls (in glibc on Linux), there are also checks for pthreads cancellation points or something, I'm not sure how this works.  And/or retries of the underlying system call transparent to the C caller.

Answer (score 0):

As @user207421 mentioned in the comment `write` being a C standard library function must eventually wrap a platform specific write system call. In MacOS facade layer is defined in `libsystem_kernel.dylib` which is utilised by MacOS C standard library implementation `libSystem.B.dylib`. The system calls number are not public interface and are subject to change across MacOS versions. Furthermore to excellent @fuz point some of them might even become obsolete and have no direct `syscall` entry/number anymore but will remain supported by the wrapper layer.

When you launch your program you can verify the actual `syscall` in action in lldb with:

```
lldb ./a.out
b write
run
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00007fff63e0f040 libsystem_kernel.dylib`write
libsystem_kernel.dylib`write:
->  0x7fff63e0f040 <+0>:  mov    eax, 0x2000004
    0x7fff63e0f045 <+5>:  mov    r10, rcx
    0x7fff63e0f048 <+8>:  syscall 
    0x7fff63e0f04a <+10>: jae    0x7fff63e0f054            ; <+20>
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
(lldb)
```

Comment: Every implementation of UNIX I have used for nearly 40 years behaves the same way. `write()` is in the C library and it executes a syscall. The fact that system call numbers are no public has no bearing . Once any application is linked the system call number is frozen forever, otherwise that application cannot run.

Comment: @user207421 fair enough, I updated the answer. But I don't agree on the system call being frozen forever as nothing stops you from dynamically resolving the call number somehow and using `syscall` directly without the wrapper layer.

Comment: @Kamil.S What can happen is that system calls stop being system calls in future versions of the operating system.  For example, `creat` could be implemented in terms of `open` which in turn can be implemented by calling `openat`.  The libc deals with these details.  However, since `creat` is no longer a system call, you cannot find its system call number by any means.

Comment: @fuz great point, I updated the answer. Don't get me wrong, I do think there's a really good reason **not to** make syscalls directly.

Comment: @user207421 there are systems which *require* that libc be linked *dynamically* for exactly that reason. Linux is the odd one out there as it's not a complete system (there's one kernel project and a separate userland project) and syscall are therefore an official and supported interface. You literally can't dynamically link libSystem on OSX (or kernel32/ntdll on windows), and while it's possible on BSDs it's really not recommended.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the lldb output, I wouldn't have thought to place the breakpoint in write !